# Configure ASP.NET Core Module to host on https instead of http for IdentityServer 4

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, identityserver4

The problem I have is when I try to host an implementation of IdentityServer4 on a IIS server that uses SSL. (Full SSL Strict)

When running my application on Kestrel alone with SSL activated it works fine and the `IssuerUri` and `Discovery Endpoints` for IdentityServer uses SSL binding. However when I host it behind ASP.NET Core Module it hosts it on `http://localhost:{random port}`, which in turn generates `IssuerUri` and `Endpoints` for Identityserver that are not https.

I have tried the following without success:

1. Made sure that I have a valid certificate on the IIS website for the
   https binding and removed binding on port 80
2. Tried changing the environmentvariable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` in web.config
   to point to a https address.
3. Tried rewrite and redirect rules in web.config.
4. Looked for settings on `IISOptions` (used by `.UseIISIntegration()`)
   in my startup class to bind to a specific url or change protocol.
5. Tried to find a similar settings like `RequireSSL` (IdentityServer 3) or
   `RequireHttpsMetadata` in IdentityServer4.
6. Changed the `IssuerUri` in IdentityServer Options in startup class
   hoping  that it might also update the other endpoints.

I have probably missed something very obvious but right now I do not have a clue on what that might be.

Any help from the community would be greatly appreciated :-)

> Program.cs code

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "IdentityServer";

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("kestrelHosting.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                // options.ThreadCount = 4;
                options.NoDelay = true;
                options.UseHttps("VismaCert.pfx", "Visma123");
                //options.UseConnectionLogging();
            })
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspNetCoreModule is an SSL terminator, it will not communicate with Kestrel over HTTPS. What it does do is forward the original scheme via a header so you can use it when generating urls/links. There is a ForwardedHeaders middleware included by default with UseIISIntegration that will take these headers and apply them to the request fields. However, there are situations where the headers cannot be processed by the default settings. There are a bunch of references here: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/2384

Comment: Thank you @Tratcher for your response. After following your links and added the response headers in the ARR I now get the following. "X-FORWARDED-HOST: xxxxxxxx.xxx.xxx", "X-FORWARDED-SCHEMA: https", "X-FORWARDED-PROTO: https, http" and "X-Forwarded-For: xx.xx.x.xx:xxxxxx". Unfortunately it seems that identityserver  does not pick up on these changes but instead reads the HttpContext.Request.Schema instead of checking if a Request.Header["X-Forwarded-Proto"] with  a value of https has been set for it's BaseUrlMiddleware, so I will address a new question to them on how to best proceed.

Comment: On forwarded headers options disable require header symmetry. Your proto and For have a different number of values.

Comment: Hi, yes I wondered that myself how the middleware would be able to pick up on which protocol to use if both were present. As it is now I have this set in code but I still get double values and also not picking up on https.  `app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto,
            ForwardLimit = null,
            RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
        });`  If I had things setup correctly would then HttpContext.Request.Schema replace it's value set to https instead of http?

Comment: Yes, if you get the right settings then Request.Scheme will be https. Try ForwardLimit = 2

Comment: I tried as you suggested setting `ForwardLimit = 2` but it still only sets Request.Schema as http. I still have both "https" and "http" as set values in the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header. The only way I could get it working is by setting it manually in code `context.Request.Scheme = "https";`. If I should set this to https or not is governed via a appsetting, but I think the way of picking it up on the forwarded proto header is a better approach if I could get it to work.